# "On file save" vs. "When the file is saved" vs. "When saving the file"

Tags: idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

The following sentences are from hypothetical manual for some text editor:

> 1. To reformat the code on file save, use the "Autoformat" feature.
> 2. To reformat the code when the file is saved, use the "Autoformat" feature.
> 3. To reformat the code when saving the file, use the "Autoformat" feature.

Which sentence sounds more natural? I tried to find some examples on Google to make my own initial research, but all the examples that I have found are from sites that are not really creditable.

Comment: All are okay, really. "On save" is a familiar usage. But there's no harm in the other two, which are even clearer. (Note: #2 makes it most clear that reformatting happens *in response* to saving.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 ("when saving the file") sounds the most natural to me.

Strictly speaking this implies that *the user who is saving the file* is the one doing the reformatting; to be completely correct it should be "To have the code reformatted when saving...." But this is unnecessary. Option 3 on its own is perfectly fine.

Option 2 (again, in a very technical sense) more correct, because it does not imply that the user is the one reformatting the file. But it does not sound as good.

Option 1 *may* be acceptable depending on the exact context; the format `OnAction` is common in JavaScript, for example the `OnClick` and `OnPageLoad` event handlers. But it should not be used in everyday English.